# Find Previous Record based on Condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a data set with the information about client's financial transactions: Deposits/Withdrawals/Bonus/Fees etc. (data sample below)
The focus question is following: Find the last Deposit preceding the Withdrawal.
I am using SMSS.

I tried to do it trough lag() but it doesn't allow filtering previous_transaction to "Deposit" only.
I did different "case when" in order by clause, but it didn't do the trick:

```
lag(transaction_no, 1) over (partition by tt.vtigeraccountid order by (case when Transaction_type_name = 'Deposit' then confirmation_time else getdate()end)
```

And

```
select lag(transaction_no, 1) over (partition by tt.vtigeraccountid order by (case when type_number = 1 then confirmation_time + type_number end)) prev_deposit_no
from (select *, case when Transaction_type_name = 'Deposit' then 1 else 2 end as type_number from Panda_Transaction_Type_Name) as tt
```

Is there other a way to do it in SQL server?

Thank you in advance,

Data sample

```
account_no  confirmation_time   transaction_no  Transaction_type_name
ACC11050231 2022-07-05 11:52:07.000 MTT500596   Deposit
ACC11050231 2022-07-05 12:08:11.000 MTT500607   Bonus
ACC11050231 2022-07-08 12:09:35.000 MTT501949   Deposit
ACC11050231 2022-07-08 12:11:09.000 MTT501950   Deposit
ACC11050231 2022-07-08 12:12:34.000 MTT501951   Deposit
ACC11050231 2022-07-08 12:14:17.000 MTT501953   Deposit
ACC11050231 2022-07-08 13:13:42.000 MTT501985   Bonus
ACC11050231 2022-09-14 07:35:55.000 MTT523696   Withdrawal
ACC11050231 2022-09-14 07:35:06.000 MTT525085   BonusCancelled
ACC11050231 2022-09-14 07:37:01.000 MTT525091   Fee
ACC11050231 2022-09-14 07:40:50.000 MTT525099   Withdrawal
ACC11050231 2022-09-14 07:41:01.000 MTT525100   Fee
ACC11050231 2022-09-14 07:48:00.000 MTT525107   Withdrawal
ACC11050231 2022-09-14 07:48:18.000 MTT525109   Fee
```

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Comment: You need an `OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1`

Comment: Hi Dale, sorry about that. I added the data sample now as code hope its the format you mean.

Comment: Hi Charlie, thanks for the suggestions. this function is new to me and I'm playing with it now but still not getting the result. can you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it, in case someone else runs into this same issue!

I did a a second table only for deposits and found a next deposit with lean().
Then joined it with the main table on client accountID with the condition that the transaction date have to fall between the dates of the deposit and corresponding next deposit (in case there is no next deposit in line I replaced it with future date)

```
select *
from
(
    select acc.account_no, tt.vtigeraccountid, transaction_no, Transaction_type_name, confirmation_time, usdamount
    from Panda_Transaction_Type_Name as tt 
    inner join Panda_Real_Deposited_Clients as acc on acc.login=tt.login
    where 1=1
    and transactionapproval = 'approved'
) as A
left join 
( -----deposit table---B
    select acc.account_no, tt.vtigeraccountid, transaction_no, Transaction_type_name, confirmation_time as start_time, usdamount
    , case when (
               lead(confirmation_time, 1) over (partition by tt.vtigeraccountid order by confirmation_time) ) is null then '3030-01-01'
          else lead(confirmation_time, 1) over (partition by tt.vtigeraccountid order by confirmation_time) end as end_time
    ,lead(transaction_no, 1)    over (partition by tt.vtigeraccountid order by confirmation_time) as prev_deposit_no  ----future deposit
    from Panda_Transaction_Type_Name as tt 
    inner join Panda_Real_Deposited_Clients as acc on acc.login=tt.login
    where 1=1
    and transactionapproval = 'approved'
    and Transaction_type_name in ('Deposit')
) as B on A.vtigeraccountid=B.vtigeraccountid and A.confirmation_time>B.start_time and A.confirmation_time<=B.end_time
```